Calculate Covered Interest Parity rates - USDTRY
Thinking about USDTRY as an example. The quotes that you see in BBG's FRD function for usdtry fwds are (to my understanding) 'market' rates. That hold some risk premia such that the rates is not identical to the rate under pure CIP. How does one calculate the pure CIP rate? or more importantly where does one get the correct try rates to do so? If you can direct me to where it sits in BBG that would be ideal.
